# Github Package Registry not overwriting tag when pushing a docker image

Tags: docker, github-package-registry

I've pushed a docker image named `com.tejas:tejas-api:dev` to the github package registry. Now, when I again push the same image name (having updated code) on to the registry, it gets pushed successfully, but does not update the image. As a result, now I have two image versions: dev (with the build time from my first deploy), and docker-base-layer (with build time of my second and most recent deploy).

[image: current image versions in package registry]

Am I doing something wrong? Or is it a GitHub Package Registry bug?

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is a bug with GitHub's Package Registry. I have contacted GitHub support but am yet to hear back.

Comment: I've done that as well. I haven't heard back from them yet. Do let me know if you hear something back. I'll do the same. Thanks for replying!

Comment: I don't think Github allow overwriting of Docker tags, as they have a policy of image/package immutability. They are also reluctant to allow package deletion for the same reason.

Comment: I've also had problems with the `docker-base-layer` image and asked Github support about it. Their reply: "The docker-base-layer version is a meta tag that is used as a place holder for all package_files/image_layers for a docker package. It was not intended to be shown, so you can safely ignore it and it will be removed in a future update."